# Buildozer Error: "ios.codesign.debug" key missing, you must give a certificate name to use

Tags: python, ios, kivy, buildozer

I attempting to package an app built in Kivy for ios, but when I run "buildozer.spec", I get this error:

```
   # 2 error(s) found in the buildozer.spec
   [app] "ios.codesign.debug" key missing, you must give a certificate
    name to use.
   [app] "ios.codesign.release" key missing, you must give a
   certificate name to use.
```

I believe this has to do with the specifics in buildozer.spec, but I am not sure which I am supposed to change. Does anyone have any ideas? Thank you.

Here is the ios part of the buildozer.spec file:

(str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the debug version
 Get a list of available identities: buildozer ios list_identities
ios.codesign.debug = "iPhone Developer:   ()"

(str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the release version
ios.codesign.release = %(ios.codesign.debug)s

Does this mean I may need an Apple Developer License?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just ran into the same problem and found this, hope it helps!

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html

Comment: Links go dead sometimes.  It would be great if you could also provide a brief summary of why the link would be helpful.

Comment: Just adding to this answer. When you create your certificate in XCode, you need to open up you Keyring, click on Login, then the My Certificates tab. Double click to open and epand the Trust section. Then select Always Trust. Once you have done this if you run buildozer ios list_identities you will now see the certificate listed. copy the section starting with "Apple Development: yourname@yourdomain (hex number)" and replace the line in the buildozer.spec "iPhone Developer: <Last Name> <First Name> (<Hex Number>) with this.